Can't Import Modules (ImportError: cannot import name...)
new to programming, and I've searched everywhere (including here) before posting.
Basically, I'm trying to recreate the ''hangman'' game, where I'd like to import both the
words, and the ascii art from modules as oppose to lengthening my code.
since the problem occurs in both modules, I'll just use one as an example:
#1 file - Practice_Hangman.py
    from hangman_words import words_list
    import random
    Target_word = random.choice(words_list)
    .
    .
    .

#2 file - hangman_words.py
    words_list = [" banana", "camel", "monkey"]

I made sure everything was properly labeled (to my level of knowledge)
I don't see any circular dependency (only one using data from another)
all the files are located together :
(folder) Coding_Journey
----(folder) Practice Hangman
--------(file)Practice_Hangman.py
--------(file) hangman_words.py
the error that I got was :
from hangman_words import words_list
ImportError: cannot import name 'words_list' from 'hangman_words'

How do you run the script?

Is this a minimal example that reproduces the error? That is, a [mcve]? So if I set up a project like yours (with the directories and files), and use these four lines of code, I should get your error?

I run it on VS code, basically just press the start button and get this error. The rest of the code works smoothly (tried it out with said list inside the code at first, and it had no problems choosing from it), so I believe it's the minimal reproducible example (learned something new today so thank you mate!) to my ,very limited knowledge, all I did was to organize the files together so the directories should be fine. right ?

Is there any logging output to see what you're actually running under the hood? Like in the terminal, or somewhere else?

For debugging purposes, insert the line import os; print(os.getcwd()) near the top of Practice_Hangman.py, and check the output (probably in the console or similar).

Could you copy-paste the full error (as text, and format as it code for readability)?

umm, can you please elaborate on those terms ? ' logging outputs' 'running under the hood' ? And I made sure I copied the error as it was, just omitted the file directories presented earlier due to privacy concerns. I did run the command you asked, but I'd you to tell me the right flow of hierarchy if possible. Do you think a reset to the computer might just do the trick ?

Well, do you see any output(s) anywhere? And if you ran that command, what is its output?

A reset is unlikely to solve your problem (though it often does), but unless this is not your personal computer or it's running important things 24/7, that's easy to find out.

When I say under thood, I mean that VS Code is running a Python command, catching its output and its error message, and sometimes hiding these things (partly) from the user. Which can be really annoying to debug, since you get only half the information. So for example, your error message should have > symbols, be formatted across a few lines at least, and possibly contain line numbers related to the files. So either VS Code has hidden those, or you didn't copy-paste the exact full error message here.

I think you just have a typo in hangman_words.py where "word" in word_list is not plural, but in the other file is referred to as words_list.

oh no, it's my bad. I did a typo while typing this here. In my code they both appear as 'words_list' ( VS code highlights it as well, I think it means it recognizes its existance ?)
I just edited it now. Thanks for spotting it !
